# Keyboard shortcut to paste text in lowercase

Tags: clipboard

I was using ten clips on Windows as a clipboard utility, and it had this nice feature that you could assign keyboard shortcut so that the text in the clipboard would be pasted but all lowercase.
Is there a utility that could do that in Ubuntu? Is it possible to configure it?

Comment: Gedit has a "Change case" extension. You could paste into Gedit, select all, change case, then cut again.

Answer (score 2):

That sounds useful... I do that very untidily like this...

Paste the text into a terminal (making sure it doesn't have any destructive commands or end with a new line.)

Press <kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>a</kbd> to go to the start
Press <kbd>alt</kbd>+<kbd>l</kbd> repeatedly or hold it down to lowercase each word. 
Copy the text to the clipboard...